# Daily Local Notification In Swift iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, ios9.2

Trying to send a daily local notification in swift. However it just sends every minute for some reason. I want the first notification to send 30 mins after the app is opened and then repeat this notification everyday.

in the swift fie i have the following code:

//---------Daily notification code (also add section in app delagate----------
        let theDate = NSDate()

```
    let dateComp = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.minute = 30

    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let fireDate:NSDate = cal.dateByAddingComponents(dateComp , toDate: theDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!


    let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

    //choosing what it says in the notification and when it fires
    notification.alertBody = "Your Daily Motivation is Awaits"

    notification.fireDate = fireDate


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

    //displaying notification every day
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day



    //-------------end of daily notification code---------------
```

in my app delegate file i have the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //----------daily notification section ----------
    let notiftypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert.union(UIUserNotificationType.Badge).union(UIUserNotificationType.Sound)

    let notifSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notiftypes, categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notifSettings)

    return true
    //----------end of daily notification section-----------
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the repeat interval after scheduling the notification. Just set the notification property before scheduleLocalNotification and make sure you schedule it only once:

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Your Daily Motivation is Awaits"
// You should set also the notification time zone otherwise the fire date is interpreted as an absolute GMT time
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
// you can simplify setting your fire date using dateByAddingTimeInterval
notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(1800) 
// set the notification property before scheduleLocalNotification
notification.repeatInterval = .Day
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Note: UIUserNotificationType are  OptionSetType structures, so you can simplify its declaration also:

```
let notiftypes:UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
```