# Convert NSCalendarUnit to Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, nscalendar

I have the next code:

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Message" // text that will be displayed in the notification
    notification.fireDate = NSDate()  // right now (when notification will be fired)
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName // play default sound

    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components([.Minute], fromDate: NSDate())

    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour // this line defines the interval at which the notification will be repeated
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

but it's deprecated. Searched a lot, but couldn't convert it to Swift2. Can anyone help me with the line:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I did, but it doesn't work. It doesn't send notification =/

Comment: Checki this have you registered for notifications? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34575836/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus yes. On the first launch it asks me about notifications.  
I've putted all lines above into showNotification() func and call it on viewWillDisappear. But it even doesn't call at all

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations in Swift 2 are much better then in Objective-C.

Try the next line:

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Hour
```

It should be working.

Comment: but it doesn't work at all =/

Comment: Which error are you getting? That means that the problem is not in this line.

Comment: I've putted all lines above into `showNotification()` func and call it on `viewWillDisappear`. But it even doesn't call at all

Comment: So, why you have decided that the problem is at this line of code?

Comment: no, it was. But thanks your answer I solved it. But it still doesn't work, that's why I've asked you. It would be great if you'll help me with it