# How to set a weekly local notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uilocalnotification

I've got a problem with my code.

I want to set a local notification in xcode7, I'm developing a calendar where you can put your university's courses, the thing is that I'm getting the schedule from a json database and I want to notify 15 min before the class starts, but I do not know why my code is not working.

This is an example where I want to repeat the notification every Monday at 13:40.

Can I only set the day and the hour? or should I specify the month and the year too?

```
  var dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    dateComp.day = 01;
    dateComp.hour = 13;
    dateComp.minute = 40;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    var calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    var date:NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.alertBody = "Swipe to unlock"
    notification.alertAction = "You've got a class soon!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.userInfo = ["CustomField1": "w00t"]
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: You need to set your notification timezone to local

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34575836/2303865

Answer (score 1):

**Weekly Local notification for swift 4

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "LocalNotification"
    content.subtitle = "notify"
    content.body = "I am Text"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
```

// Configure the recurring date.

```
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

    dateComponents.weekday = 3
    dateComponents.hour = 13
    dateComponents.minute = 10

    // Create the trigger as a repeating event.
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    // Create the request
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                                        content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the request with the system.
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            // Handle any errors.
            print("************Error***************")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this function

```
func setLNotification(weekDay:Int , hour:Int, min:Int, second:Int, alertBody:String, type:String, isRepeate:Bool){
    let calender = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
    let dateComp: NSDateComponents?
    let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

    if weekDay > 0{
        components.setValue(-50, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Year)

        let previousDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
        dateComp = calender?.components([.Year,.WeekOfMonth,.Month], fromDate: previousDate)
        dateComp?.hour = hour
        dateComp?.minute = min
        dateComp?.second = second
        dateComp?.weekday = weekDay
    }else{
        components.setValue(hour, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Hour)
        components.setValue(min, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Minute)
        components.setValue(second, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Second)
        let notifiDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
        dateComp = calender?.components([.Year,.Month,.Day,.Hour,.Minute,.Second], fromDate: notifiDate)
    }

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    if isRepeate == true{
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
        notification.repeatCalendar = calender
    }
    notification.fireDate = calender?.dateFromComponents(dateComp!)
    notification.alertBody = alertBody
    notification.userInfo = ["day":"\(weekDay)","type":"\(type)"]

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```